# What does opposite quadratic residuosity mean?

Tags: number-theory

What does it mean that $r+b \mod p$  and  $r-b \mod p$ have opposite quadratic residuosity? Where $p$ is a prime number and $r,p,b \in \mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: depends how you want to use them;  it does mean that $r^2 - b^2$  is a nonresidue mod $p,$  which is certainly allowed. $ 2^2 - 1^2 \equiv 3 \pmod 5$

Comment: @WillJagy, I'm just confused on the definition to be honest. I think residue in this term just means the representative in the equivalence classes from which we form the group $\mathbb{Z}_{p}$, but I'm quite confused as to what "opposite quadratic residuosity" means.

Comment: Presumably it means that one of them is a quadratic residue and the other is not.

Comment: @BillDubuque I see that makes sense in the context of the homework problem. Thanks!